# jquery sort list based on data attribute value

Tags: jquery

Given the following list

```
<ul class="listitems">
    <li data-position="1">Item 1</li>
    <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
    <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
    <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

there is some functionality on the page that will allow the possibility of these items changing position.  For example, they may get to the following state (example only, the order could be anything):

```
<ul class="listitems">
    <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
    <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
    <li data-position="1">Item 1</li>
    <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

I am looking for a small function to reset the order.  So far I have the following:

```
function setPositions()
{
    $( '.listitems li' ).each(function() {
        var position = $(this).data('position');
        $(this).siblings().eq(position+1).after(this);
    });
}
```

But it isnt working correctly.  What am i doing wrong?

An additonal condition is that the order of the list might not have changed, and so the function has to work in that scenario also.

Comment: Are any events bound directly to the list elements themselves? If not you could possibly just use `$('.listitems').html(function(){ return this.innerHTML; });`

Comment: There is just this question on the internals of sort() going http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598566/explain-why-array-sort-act-this-way

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Try to use [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto),

```
$(".listitems li").sort(sort_li) // sort elements
                  .appendTo('.listitems'); // append again to the list
// sort function callback
function sort_li(a, b){
    return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;    
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".listitems li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.listitems');
  function sort_li(a, b) {
    return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listitems">
  <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
  <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
  <li data-position="1">Item 1</li>
  <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does `appendTo()` replace the elements?

Comment: Yes, you can say. For testing you can check your console by using `console.log($(".listitems li").sort(sort_li));` which will give you the sorted list. No doubt here, `$('.listitems').html($(".listitems li").sort(sort_li));` will give you the same result as expected.

Comment: appendTo() is to MOVE element into specific container element in last position. jQuery documentation explained it all. :)

Comment: Item I not coming on top

Comment: Add `data-position` to all li elements(see `kalu` and `gudiya`), otherwise it breaks the sort logic.

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda , @RohanKumar Can any animations be added while sorting the elements? bcuz sometimes, it's visible that `li` move while arranging themselves

Comment: @Vikrant you can try jquery ui or any jquery sorting plugin available on the internet

Answer (score 13):

Expanding on Rohan's answer, if you want this to work for multiple lists rather than just one, you can use the following:

HTML:

```
<ul class="listitems autosort">
    <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
    <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
    <li data-position="1">Item 1</li>
    <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="listitems autosort">
    <li data-position="5">Item 5</li>
    <li data-position="6">Item 6</li>
    <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
    <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".listitems.autosort").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).children('li').sort(function(a, b){
        return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;
    }));
});
```

That will allow you to add as many lists as you like and sort them all by just setting the class autosort.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/D2NtS/653/)

Comment: this is beautifuly made  you just saved my day

Answer (score 6):

My proposal, in full javascript, is:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.listitems li')).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.getAttribute('data-position').localeCompare(b.getAttribute('data-position'));
  }).forEach(function(currValue) {
    currValue.parentNode.appendChild(currValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="listitems">
    <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
    <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
    <li data-position="1">Item 1</li>
    <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function sortList() {
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("id01");
  switching = true;
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
     
    // start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    // Loop through all list-items:
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      // start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* check if the next item should
      switch place with the current item: */
     //alert(b[i].getAttribute("order"));
      if (b[i].getAttribute("order").toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].getAttribute("order").toLowerCase()) {
        /* if next item is alphabetically
        lower than current item, mark as a switch
        and break the loop: */
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark the switch as done: */
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
      switching = true;       
    }
  }
}
```

```html
 <button onclick="sortList()">Sort List</button>
 
 <ul id="id01">
    <li order="A" class="disname disheader">Pending</li>
    <li order="AA" class="disname">302-1 Energy Consumption</li>
    <li order="AA" class="disname">302-3 Energy Intensity</li>
    <li order="DD" class="disname">EN-31 Environmental Expenditure/Investment</li>
    <li order="DD" class="disname">103-2  Environmental Grievances</li>
    <li order="D" class="disname disheader">Deactive</li>                               
    <li order="BB" class="disname">305-4  Emission Intensity</li>                             
    <li order="BB" class="disname">306-2 Total Waste</li>
    <li order="BB" class="disname">307-1 Compliance</li>
    <li order="AA" class="disname">302-4 Energy/Electricity Reduction Initiative</li>
    <li order="AA" class="disname">303-1 Water Withdrawal by Source</li>
    <li order="AA" class="disname">303-3 Recycled Water</li>
    <li order="C" class="disname disheader">Auto Generated</li>
    <li order="CC" class="disname">305-1 GHG Emission</li>
    <li order="CC" class="disname">305-2 GHG Emission</li>
    <li order="CC" class="disname">305-3 GHG Emission</li>
    <li order="BB" class="disname">05-5 Reduction of GHG Emissions</li>
    <li order="BB" class="disname">306-1 Water Discharge</li>  
    <li order="B" class="disname disheader">Overdue</li>                              
</ul>
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/udarakasun/pen/rRNKJG)

Answer (score 0):

What about using `sort` and replace inside `DOM`

```js
function sortLiElements(a,b) {
 return parseInt($(a).data('position')) -   parseInt($(b).data('position'));
}

$('.listitems').html($('.listitems li').sort(sortLiElements));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listitems">
    <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
    <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
    <li data-position="1">Item 1</li>
    <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```