# how to Sort dynamiclly created html div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically created html div using jquery , now i want to sort the div's according to date/Name. the dynamically created div are like ,

```
<div class="itemBox" data-date="2013-12-12 00:00:00" data-name="Simple Choker">
    ..data1.
<div>

<div class="itemBox" data-date="2013-12-12 00:00:00" data-name="Double 22"">
    ..data2.
<div>
```

Jquery that i have used

```
$.each(results, function (index, items) 
{ 
    var appendData = "";
    appendData = appendData + "<div class='itemBox' data-name='" + items.name+    "'data-date='" + items.createdDate + "'>";  
    //images are appended using Api // 
    appendData = appendData + "</div>"; 
    $(".mainDiv").append(appendData); 
}
```

How to do it using jquery? Do i need any plugin or function?

Comment: Where's the jQuery that's generating the output? JSFiddle please.

Comment: Sort them before you append them

Comment: @johan- i have to sort them after they are loaded

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600802/jquery-sort-list-based-on-data-attribute-value - try the solution there.

Comment: @denisol-jquery is like


$.each(results, function (index, items) {
                var appendData = "";
                appendData = appendData + "<div class='itemBox' data-name='" + items.name + "' data-date='" + items.createdDate + "'>";

//images are appended using Api //
      appendData = appendData + "</div>";
               
                $(".mainDiv").append(appendData);

Comment: as already mentioned, just sort `results` before generating html

Comment: Put your code in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Add each element to an array with the date being the key, then you can use the array sort method before adding them to the page, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to sort the JS object before generating the HTML. But since you want to do it after generation, Try this code

```
$(".itemBox").sort(function (a, b) {
    var d1 = new Date($(a).data('date'));
    var d2 = new Date($(b).data('date'));
    return d2 < d1 ? 1 : -1;
}).appendTo('body');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0p0m7ky0/)