# Sorting li in unordered list based on data attribute with varying length (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

So I found this neat implementation to sort a list based on data-attributes:
[jquery sort list based on data attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600802/jquery-sort-list-based-on-data-attribute-value)

The trouble I have is that my data attributes have varying length and mixed letters and numbers so the sorting falls a little short, here's an example based on the above solution:

```
<ul class="listitems">
  <li data-position="test3">Item 3</li>
  <li data-position="test2">Item 2</li>
  <li data-position="test1">Item 1</li>
  <li data-position="test4">Item 4</li>
  <li data-position="test23">Item 23</li>
  <li data-position="test35">Item 35</li>
  <li data-position="test33">Item 33</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ddLp14pp/1/

I'd like the ordering of the numbers to be incremental (1,2,3,4,25,33,35 etc), but I can't solve it and I can't find anything on here or google.

PS. The sorting is based on data-attribute because the `<li>` contains several `<a>` and `<span>`

Comment: This would be much easier with the word "test" being in the position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort numerically rather than alphabetically, so remove the word test and convert to a number, then compare. As so:

```
$(".listitems li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.listitems');
function sort_li(a, b){
    return (+$(b).data('position').replace("test","")) <     (+$(a).data('position').replace("test","")) ? 1 : -1;    
}
```

Comment: I was a bit hasty so I forgot to mention it's not always "test" before the numbers, so I would need to do both. Nonetheless this answers the question I posed.