# Iterate through elements to sort their childrens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to iterate through all the elements with a specific class to sort their children based on their value attributes. I need to sort the children separately for each parent elements.

Html structure :

```
<ul class="parentClass">
   <li value="1">...</li>
   <li value="10">...</li> 
   <li value="8">...</li> 
</ul>
<ul class="parentClass">
   <li value="8">...</li>
   <li value="29">...</li> 
   <li value="5">...</li> 
</ul>
```

JS code :

```
function sortAll() {
    $(".parentClass").each(function() {
        var items = $(this).children("li").sort(function(a, b) {
        var vA = $("li", a).attr("value");
        var vB = $("li", b).attr("value");
        return (vA > vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 0 : 1;
        });
        $(this).append(items);
    });
}
```

What I'm trying to get :

```
<ul class="parentClass">
   <li value="10">...</li>
   <li value="8">...</li> 
   <li value="1">...</li> 
</ul>
<ul class="parentClass">
   <li value="29">...</li>
   <li value="8">...</li> 
   <li value="5">...</li> 
</ul>
```

I think I misunderstood something with iteration. Could you help me to figure out my mistake?

I would also let you know that some `<li>` elements could have the same value.

**Solution :**

```
function sortAll() {
        $(".parentClass").each(function() {
            var items = $(this).children("li").sort(function(a, b) {
            var vA = $(a).attr("value");
            var vB = $(b).attr("value");
            return (vA > vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 0 : 1;
            });
            $(this).append(items);
        });
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery sort list based on data attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600802/jquery-sort-list-based-on-data-attribute-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(a)` and `$(b)` instead of the `$("li", a)` and `$("li", b)`. `a` and `b` refer to the `li` elements. You are trying to find the descendant `li`s of the `li` elements (`$(selector, context)` is the same as `$(context).find(selector)`). The queries return empty collections and subsequently `attr` returns an `undefined` value. Both `undefined > undefined` and `undefined < undefined` return `false`. The `sort` callback always returns `0` which leaves the order unchanged.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I'll check the answer as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at example of descending sorting with your data. There are a good answer about [array sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979325/2294657) with a description for algorithm.

The ternary operator `(vA > vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 0 : 1` that you have used is behaving weird, resulting in wrong order.

> - If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than    b, i.e. a comes first.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a    and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect    to all different
>     elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not    guarantee this
>     behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla    versions dating
>     back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than    a. compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value
>     when given    a specific pair of elements a and b as its two
>     arguments.
> - If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined

If `vA > vB // true` sort a to a lower index than b

Therefore if `vA < vB // true` leave a and b unchanged. This is a logical error.

```js
function sortAll() {
  
  // Define variables before loops.
  var $container, $itemsColl;
  
  $(".parentClass").each(function(key, value) {
    
    // <ul> tag
    $container = $(value);
    $itemsColl = $container.children("li");
    
    // Sort and appendTo() <ul>.
    $itemsColl.sort(function(a, b) {

        // Inverted for descendant sorting.
        return $(b).attr('value') - $(a).attr('value');
      })
      .appendTo($container);
  });
}

sortAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parentClass">
  <li value="1">1</li>
  <li value="10">10</li>
  <li value="8">8</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parentClass">
  <li value="8">8</li>
  <li value="29">29</li>
  <li value="5">5</li>
</ul>
```