# Django - Changing order_by on click

Tags: python, django

Using Django and I would like to change the order of the display of the objects on click without refreshing the page.

my model

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'movies/index.html'
    page_template = 'movies/all_movies.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_movies'
    model = Movie

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'all_genres': Genre.objects.all(),
            'our_pick': Movie.objects.get(pk=259)
        })
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Movie.objects.all()
```

And this is my **index.html**

```
<menu class="menu">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Newest</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Most Popular</a></li>
   </ul>
</menu>
```

on clink on Newest, the query will become:

```
Movie.objects.all().order_by('release_date')
```

and on click on Most popular, the query will become:

```
Movie.objects.all().order_by('popularity')
```

How can I achieve that without refreshing the page? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're gonna want to do this this on the front-end, with jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to illustrate a misunderstanding of how front-end and back-end languages work: a click event occurs on the front-end, *after* the data has been sent from the server. The `order_by` function is run and completed *before* the request is completed.

To load new data from the server without reloading, you will have to send a new request in the background using AJAX.

This is probably **not a good idea**, though, since you are sending the same query set ordered in a different way. I recommend using JS or jQuery to order the list on a click event based on a `data` attribute that you can set in the list itself. For more information about how to do this, see [jquery sort list based on data attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600802/jquery-sort-list-based-on-data-attribute-value).

Comment: Thank you for your help!