# jquery Save the order before sorting

Tags: javascript, save

I would need your help, I have a long list similar to the following:

```
<div id="works">
<div class="item" data-date="20160312">Item2</div>
<div class="item" data-date="20170227">Item5</div>
<div class="item" data-date="20051201">Item1</div>
<div class="item" data-date="20010515">Item3</div>
<div class="item" data-date="20100418">Item4</div>
….
</div>
```

I use the following method [jquery sort list based on data attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600802/jquery-sort-list-based-on-data-attribute-value) to sort the items by date, categories ... but I would need to save the initial order before sorting.
The ideal would be, for example, to create a function that would add a "data-origin" like this:

```
<div id="works">
<div class="item" data-origin="1" data-date="20160312">Item2</div>
<div class="item" data-origin="2" data-date="20170227">Item5</div>
<div class="item" data-origin="3" data-date="20051201">Item1</div>
<div class="item" data-origin="4" data-date="20010515">Item3</div>
<div class="item" data-origin="5" data-date="20100418">Item4</div>
….
</div>
```

Do you have a solution ? (I also use infinitescroll which loads the continuation of the lite, it would also be necessary that I could add this "data-origin" to the new elements)
Thank you very much !

Comment: Why no jQuery tag if you already use a jQuery solution for sorting? With jQuery that's easily done with an [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) -> [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: Without jQuery: [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) + [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) + [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.item').each(function(index){ $(this).data('origin-order', index) })

$('.item').each(function(index){ console.log($(this).data('origin-order')) })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="works">
<div class="item" data-date="20160312">Item2</div>
<div class="item" data-date="20170227">Item5</div>
<div class="item" data-date="20051201">Item1</div>
<div class="item" data-date="20010515">Item3</div>
<div class="item" data-date="20100418">Item4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's perfect !!!
Sorry I'm a beginner, I was looking for more complicated ...

Thank you everyone!