# Order parent by number that exists in the child item using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have ul li with a number inside the li, how can I order all the ul by this number (the Higher should be first)?

For example I have that html that I can't change

```
<ul id="ul-list">
    <li>
        <div class="name">product 1</div>
        <div class="rating">85</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="name">product 2</div>
        <div class="rating">20</div>
   </li>
    <li>

        <div class="name">product 3</div>
        <div class="rating">95</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want re-order that list so product 3 will be the first one because that item has the highest rating, and product 2 will be the last one because that product has the lowest rating

Comment: May be interested in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600802/jquery-sort-list-based-on-data-attribute-value)

Comment: Btw your html is not correct. There are some `<li>` without content. Also it's better to sort when constructing the html, either with php or any other backend or data support.

Comment: thanks, it's correct now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert toArray, sort that array, empty the container and finally add the sorted array of elements.

```js
var sorted = $('#ul-list li').toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
  var aValue = $(a).find('.rating')[0].textContent;
  var bValue = $(b).find('.rating')[0].textContent;

  return bValue - aValue;
});


$('#ul-list').empty().append(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul-list">
    <li>
        <div class="name">product 1</div>
        <div class="rating">85</div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="name">product 2</div>
        <div class="rating">20</div>
    </li>
        
    <li>
      <div class="name">product 3</div>
        <div class="rating">95</div>
    </li>
        
</ul>
```

Comment: I was just starting a Plunker for this when your answer came up, so I dropped your code into my Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/G4RYc5T2xjcyY82iyuMI?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider adding a data attribute that stores the value using `jQuery`.  You can then create a function in `JavaScript` that:

1) grabs this stored number with jQuery,

2) adds it to an array,

3) sort the array with a method, and

4) use jQuery to post the results in the order you want.

If you wanted to store data in the HTML you can do so like this:

```
$("your selector").attr("data-value", your value);
```