# fancybox V3 + isotope sort by

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope, fancybox-3

I'll need your help: I'm using isotope to sort thumbnails that are also open with fancybox. Until then I used fancybox V2 it worked perfectly! (I followed the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600802/jquery-sort-list-based-on-data-attribute-value/21600865#21600865))
But I just switched to Fancybox V3, I can not sort my images in fancybox ...

```
<div id="gallery">
  <div class="item" data-date="20130731">Image B</div>
  <div class="item" data-date="20140320">Image A</div>
  <div class="item" data-date="20130719">Image D</div>
  <div class="item" data-date="20120922">Image C</div>
</div>
```

And the js:

```
$("#works .item").sort(sort_li).appendTo('#gallery');

function sort_li(a, b){
    return ($(b).data('date')) < ($(a).data('date')) ? 1 : -1;    
}
```

Looks like fancybox does not update this list...
Do you have any ideas ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Please, provide full sample code or better a live demo.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that when I delete the fancybox options with the following code: (same empty as below)

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
});
```

the function sorts by works very well!