# Order List Items by data value

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

How can i set sort of li items by data valur or alternative methods?

```
<ul>
  <li id="two" data-value="3"> 1 </li>
  <li id="three" data-value="1"> 2 </li>
  <li id="one" data-value="2"> 3 </li>
</ul>
```

//Output must be 3 1 2 but i have more than 100 items

Comment: I think this is a simular question that can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600802/jquery-sort-list-based-on-data-attribute-value

Answer (score 1):

Use sorting logic on data value of `li` and update `ul` html.

```js
$("#test").html(
  $("#test").children("li").sort(function (a, b) {
    var val1= parseInt($(a).data('value'));
    var val2= parseInt($(b).data('value'));
      return val1-val2;
  })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test">
  <li id="two" data-value="3"> 1 </li>
  <li id="three" data-value="1"> 2 </li>
  <li id="one" data-value="2"> 3 </li>
</ul>
```